# How to extend the Weblogic domain template?

Tags: java, templates, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

I want to develop the Weblogic custom domain template for my application, the template should include the standalone WLS + JRF template and integrate with my application configuration.

As we know, standalone WLS + JRF template are shipped in Weblogic installation folder, the JRF is depended upon lots of other templates, Can I create my own one only to extend them? or I have to create the one which includes all of them, that is, the template jar need includes all files copying from WLS + JRF templates and also plus my configuration, I tried it was unable to do with Weblogic domain template builder wizard. it seems I need firstly create workable domain then according it to build my domain template.

Please guide me.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, you want to use an existing domain to create a template via config.sh? When the GUI pops up can't you just check `Extend my domain to support the following added products`? What errors/problems specifically are you having

Answer (score 0):

weblogic 12c don't have JRF template by default, you need install ADR(application development Runtime) as well to extend the library for weblogic, download linkage: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/downloads/index.html